# Передача кука и сессии на другой домен

Tags: авторизация, сессия, cookie, php

Подскажите, как, один раз авторизовавшись, авторизоваться на разных доменах?

Comment: Куки можно сделать только для одного домена (автоматически учесть можно поддомены). Куки одного домена не доступны другим, сделано так в целях безопасности, чтобы данные не пропадали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну что же. Можно намутить как вариант, конечно, такое -
входите на один сайт. На нем стоит внизу счетчик от других сайтов (счетчик или картинка - все равно). Адрес ее делается следующим образом - `http://имя-сайта/имя-скрипта.php?login=логин&pass=и мд5`, от пароля получая данное, скрипт делает проверку (на одном из сайтов, на котором надо авторизоваться) и дальше можете бегать между ними.

Comment: За «MD5 от пароля» в приличном обществе бъют подсвечником.

Comment: а запятую не видно нет? "и мд5, от пароля получая данное" тоесть MD5(MD5(пароль))

Comment: Не понял, по какой логике следует MD5(MD5(пароль)), но это не принципиально, хоть SHA512(SHA512(SHA512(пароль)). Ну, да, от *уже готовых* радужных таблиц можно откреститься. Но, в любом случае, эта схема: а) завязана на аутентификационные данные пользователя и б) уязвима к replay-атакам. Обе этих вещи я говорю, как что-то плохое.

Comment: при передачи данного будет временная сессия. а если говорите о перехвате то в таком случае вообще нигде не авторизуйтесь потому что перехватить можно и просто посылку на сервер в открытом виде. в данном случае в сессию передается просто данные для пользователя. при перехвате их некуда девать потому как куки будут содержать совершенно другое.

Comment: Никого не интересуют cookie, если сессия прекрасно создается парой логин-ключ. И не имеет никакого значения, какой ключ является функцией от пароля, до тех пор пока он ей является.

По поводу перехвата. Во-первых, поймать этот «псевдо-счетчик» куда проще, чем форму авторизации, в силу разности частоты показов. Во-вторых есть три волшебные буквы: XSI. Форма логина может быть не уязвима, а вот весь сайт?

Comment: Защиту уже можно по средством скрипа-движка организовать, в моем случае перехват хэшей ничего не даст "хацкеру", кроме как "белеберду" сгенерированной НЕ ОТ пар логин+пароль.

Думаю вопрос можно закрыть.

Answer (score 3):

Не надо передавать данные аутентификации. Утекут — пиши пропало. Лучше передавать данные сессии, утечка, в таком случае, намного безопаснее. Заодно позволяет реализовать не только single sign-on (единственный вход), но и single sign-out (единственный выход).

Я рассмотрю случай, когда все сайты имеют единую клиентскую базу, и есть только один сайт (из кучи), где клиент регистрируется-аутентифицируется-авторизуется. Для ситуации с распределенной, децентрализованной пользовательской базой, этот метод не походит.

Грубое описание:

1. Два домена, в разных TLD: example.org и example.com
2. Аутентификация идет на example.org.
3. Оба сайта имеют доступ к общему серверу сессий (им может являться специализированное решение типа RADIUS, БД или один из сайтов)
4. При посещении `example.com` отправляем пользователя на некий `example.org/a12n?return_uri=http://example.com/`
5. Наш example.org отрабатывает аутентификацию. Если надо — показывает форму логина и требует авторизации, если нет, создает анонимную сессию (если на сайте нужны анонимы).
6. Созданная example.org сессия запоминается на сервере сессий. Сессия идентифицируется по некоторому уникальному значению (ID), которое трудно подобрать (генераторы энтропии в помощь). ID сессии хранится в cookies example.org.
7. Перебрасываем клиента назад на example.com, добавляя к адресу параметр `?auth.data=<ID сессии>`. Для безопасности, лучше ID пошифровать любым хорошим симметричным алгоритмом, устойчивым к known-plaintext атакам, и подписать, упомянув время, в которое этот ID был выдан, и некоторое nonce-значение (для защиты от replay-атак).
8. Наш example.com видит параметр `auth.data`, удостоверяется у сервера сессий, что такая сессия существует и корректна (здесь он узнает и кто, собственно, пользователь), сохраняет ID сессии в cookies и делает редирект сам на себя, на тот же адрес, но уже без `auth.data`.
9. В итоге, оба сайта имеют session ID (который, вообще говоря, может быть уникален для каждого сайта, и просто ссылаться на одну сессию). Задача выполнена, single sign-on реализован.
10. Для реализации single sign-out, любой из сайтов (лучше всего, один, тот же, который занимается и входом) отмечает сессию как закрытую, либо удаляет ее. Поскольку все сайты опираются на единый сервер сессий, то сессия будет закрыта везде.
11. На каком-то этапе стоит проверять, принимает ли клиент cookies, чтобы не загнать его в бесконечный цикл (и не породить при этом кучу сессий).

Собственно говоря, это такой «недо-OAuth2». Можно, кстати, и OAuth взять, даже правильнее будет. Логика, в общем смысле, та же самая — все те же токены.

Для простоты, чтобы было меньше абстракций — вариант устройства:

1. Сервер сессий — обычная реляционная БД с SQL.
2. Все сайты — одного владельца и ID сессии на всех сайтах одинаков.
3. Проверка сесии — в middleware каждого сайта делать `SELECT user_id FROM shared_sessions WHERE id = :session_id AND closed IS NULL`.
4. Создание и закрытие сессии, думаю, очевидны.

Comment: Все верно, у меня в последствии все (почти) так и реализовано, проблема была с присваиванием кукисов и сессий к другим доменам системы, чтобы проверить авторизацию юзвера на сервере сессий.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе можно воспользоваться библиотекой Curl + Jquery. 
При авторизации - через jQuery отсылать данные скрипту - а там через Curl передавать на другой домен данные авторизации.

Comment: Зачем такие геморы, если при авторинге на одном домене можно через вызов картинки передавать логин и хеш пароля на другие сервера для создания там сессий с данными. А при переходе на те домены просто логинить юзера автоматически, используя эти данные, и после уже делать на свой домен куки? Так же быстрее.

Comment: Ну допустим если в будущем планируется делать что-то типа API, то с таким хаком уже не сильно удобно. Слово "хак" для меня ничего плохого не подразумевает, просто это хак де факто, а предложение выше - "правильное" его использование. Хотя ваш вариант, бесспорно, веселее)

Правда, будет заморочка с тем, что надо будет как-то сессии отлавливать (типа по IP+UserAgent+хэш)

Comment: API не будет. Вариант со скрытыми картинками сработал нормально. Единственное, теперь пытаюсь сделать обратную связь (без API). Чтобы с другого "сайта" посылались команды этому "сайту". Но это уже мелочи. Я уже знаю как и как раз реализую.

Answer (score 0):

Ну глобально, можно завести один домен чисто  для авторизации. Напрмер auth.mysite.ru. И тогда сайты с остальными доменами просто будут опрашивать сайт с доменом авторизации, отсылая ему логин-пароль (как через веб-формы, так и через кукисы) и получая ответ - авторизован ли юзер или нет.

Comment: Он хочет, чтобы автоматически, как только зашел, авторизовался на одном, то при переходе на другой не надо было вводить больше пароль.

Comment: @Grimon да, я именно так и хочу. Я где-то читал, что можно делать скрытые картинки, которые подгружаются с других доменов, на которых нужно авторизоваться. Только я не понимаю как скрипту картинки передать данные формы.

Answer (score 0):

Можно в базе сохранять авторизацию, а на всех доменах уже проверять её.